# Pass Databinding From Child Control Through Parent UserControl

Tags: c#, data-binding, user-controls

I'm trying to build a custom usercontrol (winforms) with a richtextbox and would like to pass the "Text" databinding through the usercontrol so that when the control is placed on a form and a bindingsource is bound to the usercontrol's "Text" databinding, it will actually bind to the child richtextbox "Text" binding.  The code bit below works for setting the text but won't get the text after it has been changed.

User Control:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DefaultBindingProperty("Text")]
    public partial class UcEditableRTBox : UserControl
    {
        public UcEditableRTBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitControl();
        }

        [Bindable(true)]
        public override string Text
        {
            get { return rtb.Text; }
            set { rtb.Text = value; }
        }
```

Form:

```
public partial class FrmTest : Form
    {
        public FrmTest()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        TestTable tt;

        private void FrmTest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tt = TestTable.FindAll().FirstOrDefault();
            bindingSource.DataSource = tt;
        }

        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bindingSource.EndEdit();
            tt.Save();
        }
    }
```

Any hint's as to how to go about this or additional resources to look in to would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard fix is to use a different name other than `Text`:

```
public string TextValue {
  get { return rtb.Text; }
  set { rtb.Text = value; }
}
```

See [Data Binding with a Custom UserControl’s Text Property](http://hurcane.wordpress.com/2006/05/09/data-binding-with-a-custom-usercontrols-text-property/) for other workaround ideas.

Comment: Thanks, the above works great.  As for using the "Text" name, the code below seems to fix:

<br><code>private void rtb_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.OnTextChanged(e);
        }